# How can I convert a long table into a wide table with only a few selected columns in Clickhouse using sql?

Tags: clickhouse

given a data item with values as the given string :

{"id":1,"effect_status":16698,"error_code":null,"status_last":166900}
{"id":2,"effect_status":234433,"error_code":active,"status_last":188750}

I want to create two custom columns : error_code and the status_last

I could not solve the problem using sql in clickhouse. I tried it with python locally. I need a solution in sql.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`"error_code":active` -- is not Valid JSON. Expected "active".

```sql
create table test ( A String ) Engine = Memory as
select arrayJoin(['{"id":1,"effect_status":16698,"error_code":null,"status_last":166900}',        '{"id":2,"effect_status":234433,"error_code":"active","status_last":188750}']);

SELECT
    JSONExtractString(A, 'error_code') AS error_code,
    JSONExtractInt(A, 'status_last') AS status_last
FROM test

┌─error_code─┬─status_last─┐
│            │      166900 │
│ active     │      188750 │
└────────────┴─────────────┘
```

https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/21b750f7-ec6b-487a-a458-c24d23423353

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-schema-design/altinity-kb-jsonasstring-and-mat.-view-as-json-parser/

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/jsonextract-to-parse-many-attributes-at-a-time/

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/developer/working-with-json